# How can I use substring string function in MVEL expressions

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, mvel

I am using Studio and have a need to use MVEL expressions. Can someone please tell me how can I extract all the characters in a field after underscore character.I am reading these values from an XML file.Please see below example.

Action:

```
NEW_3456
NEW_CW234789
```

So, I want my MVEL expresion to extract all the values after underscore. So, the result for the above expression should be `3456` and `CW234789` respectively.

Here is what I am using :
Declare a variable to navigate and pick the Action field value.

Lets say the variable declared is

```
props['applicant.Status1']
```

The value of this variable is  :

```
props['applicant.Status1'] = parts[0].xpath('/row/Action/normalize-space(substring(text(),5,8))')
```

The output is `3456` and `CW23` which is fine.

Now here is the issue, in order to extract all the value aftre underscore  I used the below expression and I am not getting the deired value.

```
props['applicant.Status1'] = parts[0].xpath('/row/Action/normalize-space(substring-after(text(),5))')
```

Can someone please tell me if the above expresion is correct. Is there some other way I can get the value I am desiring. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `substring-after(text(),“5“))`

Answer (score 0):

> *"Can someone please tell me how can I extract all the characters in a field after underscore character"*

This should be straightforward given that you knew about `substring-after()` function :

```
/row/Action/normalize-space(substring-after(., "_"))
```